# How can I print scrolltop() value 0 when scroll reaches top of the div

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 div's on the same page. All div's have same class name 'post' and same height '600px'.
So what I want is when I scroll any div among 5 div and when it reaches to the top of the div it should alert the value 0.

Trouble is When I scroll div2, div3, div4, div5 to the top. It did not print value '0'. 
But when I scroll div1 to the top and then if I scroll any other div's it shows '0'. I need to print 
'0' no matter which div I am scrolling first.
Why is it happening. See the comment section for jsfiddle code. thanks in advance.

**Demo**

```
$("window").load()
{
    $('.post').scrollTop($('.post').height())  
} 

$('.post').scroll(function() {
    if($('.post').scrollTop()==0)
    {
        alert('0');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/052xntw9/11/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/052xntw9/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if($('.post').scrollTop()==0)
{
    alert('0');
}
```

to

```
if($(this).scrollTop()==0)
{
    alert('0');
}
```

`$('.post').scrollTop()` will give the value of the first `div` (first found element). If the value of the first `div` is 0, `$('.post').scrollTop() == 0` will be always `true`, even though you're scrolling  other `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You are always selecting first div. This is why you are getting that result.

In this code:

```
if($('.post').scrollTop()==0)
{
    alert('0');
}
```

*$('.post').scrollTop()* will return first found element.

Try this:

```
$('.post').scroll(function() {

    $('.post').each(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()==0)
        {
            alert('0');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh now I understand. It's really helps me to understand the problem very well. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `post` divs in a parent, and iterate through children. Then use `this` keyword to identify which child div you're scrolling:

```
$('#allPosts').children().scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        alert('0');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
$(".post").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        alert('0');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/052xntw9/19/

This will attach an event listener to each div, and the $(this) refers specifically to that div (instead of the first div).